# MongoDB Data API invalid session error with postman and python

Tags: mongodb, postman

I’m trying to Update/Post to my documents in a MongoDB database through using the Data API via postman, I followed all the steps and filled in all the essential variables and I consistently get that error.

> invalid session: error finding user for endpoint

Here it shows that I successfully forked the MongoDB Data API to my Postman collection and filled in all the necessary variables.

[First Image - Postman Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyDg8.png)

This is me making the POST request to find a document in my database (this same exact error keeps on showing with all the other endpoints, update, insert, etc…)

[Second Image - The Request And The Occurring Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aayDY.png)

And these are the header and body of the request showing that the variables were correctly setup and the the request is going through with no problems but I get that same error every time.

[Third Image - Header and Body of The Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI1jm.png)

So I figured it might be a postman thing so I tried to make the request using Python instead and I got the same exact error there too.

[Fourth Image - Python Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SURLl.png)

This is the document I am trying to send the requests to.

[Fifth Image - The database in MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvMqR.png)

And this is my Data API game with the cluster all being setup and given access for both reading and writing.

[Sixths Image - The MongoDB Data API Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCSAT.png)

So I am not sure what is exactly going on or what am I not seeing.